# Nuget not connecting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am getting the following error while trying to connect to NuGET.

wtf.

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   An error occurred while sending
>   the request.   Unable to connect to the remote server   A socket
>   operation was attempted to an unreachable network
>   [2606:2800:133:f17:19e8:2356:251b:2a9]:443

why is this happening? and why is it using ipv6?

help help

Comment: What happens when you open the URL in a browser? If you don't see any json, you probably have some firewall issues with TLS.

Comment: definitely a routing problem.

Comment: Which version of NuGet and Visual Studio do you use? Please tell us where and how do you connect to your NuGet.

Comment: Yes I am able to open the URL with my browser.

Comment: @ DarthVader, you can try to set ipv6 enabled to be false in the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config like "<ipv6 enabled="false"/>", and then check it again.

Comment: Didnt work. still the same error.

Comment: why is it trying to use ipv6? how can i disable?

Comment: I even uninstalled and re-installed VS and didnt work.

Comment: @DarthVader Aftrer disabled <ipv6 enable="false">, please restart your Visual Studio again, which will let Visual Studio reload the devenv.exe.config file.

Comment: And you also can try clear your the Proxy Cache in IE based on this document https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2289942 and read the 'Let me fix it myself' part.

Answer (score 0):

It would be related to your Proxy, you can add proxy settings in your Nuget.Config file.

You could get useful information from the [NuGet.Config Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#config-section) and [Nuget Proxy Settings](http://skolima.blogspot.sg/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html).

**Update:**

So you have resolved this issue here:

[Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)

Am I right? If so, you could close the two cases:)