# Visual Studio 2017 + Nuget

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

Please help me.

> [nuget.org] Failed to load service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.    An error occurred while
>   sending the request.    Unable to connect to remote server    The
>   attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful. from another
>   computer for the required time did not receive the desired response,
>   or the already established connection was broken because of the
>   incorrect response of the computer already connected. 72.21.81.200:443

Comment: Looks like the remote server is either down, or your internet connection is bad. Try again in a little bit.

Comment: It's difficult for someone on StackOverflow to give you help with this type of problem as no-one is going to know about you specific circumstances. This type of issue might be better raised with your own IT company support.

Maybe you can elaborate on what else you have tried to rule out other factors then someone here might be able to help: how long has this been happening? has it ever worked in the past? have you made any changes recently that may be contributing to the issue? can you reach nuget.org (or anything) in a browser ? is anyone else on the same network having the same issue?

Comment: @Oleg, really agree with pmcilreavy. Do you have proxy configured on your machine? Or "http_proxy" variable configured in environment variable? Can you reach nuget.org in a browser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source