# Error when loading Nuget packages in ASP.NET projects "Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3index.json"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

Im trying to follow the steps to make the ContosoUniversity project on https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio.

When i try to scaffold a new Razor page CRUD i got this : "Unable to load the service index for source [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22).

This problem lasts for 4 days and I dont know exactly why. I tried to reinstall my Visual studio, upgrade and downgrade versions but nothing worked...

**PS : Using Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.1.4, .NET 6.0.**

...

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDMuY.png)

Comment: That URL for the index is wrong, it should be `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`. Check the setting in Visual Studio -> Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Package Sources

Comment: You may also have a `nuget.config` file in your solution that is overriding the settings.

Comment: You can [follow the steps to check this common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773500/visual-studio-nuget-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source).([Nuget Config Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) & [Nuget Proxy Settings](https://skolima.blogspot.com/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html).)

Comment: Sorry, i missed a "/" in the URL. The message error is "Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".