# unable to load the service index for source https //api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I just installed vs and created a mvc project
But the nuget part in the references is a yellow sign, and when I try to create a controller, I encounter the "unable to load the service index for source https //api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" message.
can yu help me ?
thank you

Comment: Duplicate, probably: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41185443/1531971 (If not a dupe, you need to tell us _why_.)

Comment: isled it , my problem was beacuseof internet explorer versin ,that was version 8 , i upgrade it to versio 11 , and my problem has been resolved.    Earlier, Visual Studio 2015 was installed and is now installed, but previously only vs2017 had a problem, but both are working right now. ,      thank you very much