# Dotnet Restore fails in docker build

Tags: docker, nuget, dotnet-restore

Hello i am trying to `dockerize` a `ASP NET Core 2.1` application and the `docker build` fails when it executes `dotnet restore`.
I have already checked other threads for this specific problem  
 *[Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)*.

The solutions provided there did not help me.

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG serverPath=./Core/Server

FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app


COPY ./Core/Server/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore  //fails here

COPY ./Core/Server/ ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out  


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out  .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","Server.dll"]
```

**Output of docker build**

```
$ docker build -t server .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.13MB
Step 1/11 : ARG serverPath=./Core/Server
Step 2/11 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
 ---> 343e2dc38168
Step 3/11 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9b75480ecb9
Step 4/11 : COPY ./Core/Server/*.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2de864bedf6a
Step 5/11 : RUN dotnet restore 
 ---> Running in 2fc6963e7e2c
  Restoring packages for /app/Server.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/app/Server.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/app/Server.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. [/app/Server.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -p:RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets=false -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with .NET Core 2.2 Windows images. I too went through that other thread without success. One strange thing is that I can run Docker out of Visual Studio 2017. I only have the Nuget connection issues from the command line (even when run as administrator).

Comment: I am having similar issues. As per discussions on this thread https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6742 I seem to be having more success adding the `--disable-parallel` option to dotnet restore.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
docker network ls
```

This should list the networkIDs try running the docker build

```
docker build --network=<networkid> tag=<tag>
```

try the above with all the network listed it will work with one, that's the host network.

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me when facing this annoying 'nuget restore' network error.  thanks!

Comment: I'm running docker build from WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) and after trying this with all of the networks that show up in `docker network ls`, it still doesn't work with any of them. Some timeout instantly and one takes a while.

Comment: Turns out my issue was due to my DNS being not quite right in my WSL2. Posting another answer below...

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your DNS Server to be Fixed (default should be `8.8.8.8`).

I found this in Settings-> Network -> DNS Server

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this same error while trying to build a docker image within WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) running on my Windows machine.

In my case, I confirmed that I could hit nuget from my WSL2 with:

```
curl -v https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

But then if I tried that same request from a Docker container, it could not resolve the hostname (this would just hang):

```
docker run -it --rm curlimages/curl -v -k https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

So this pointed to an issue with DNS and since Docker uses your "host" DNS config, I focused on my WSL2 DNS. I was using the default DNS that WSL2 uses. This means `/etc/resolv.conf` is auto-generated... I turned that off following the instructions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1533291/how-do-i-change-the-dns-settings-for-wsl2

The DNS I then manually configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` was my company's internal DNS server. After restarting WSL2 and Docker, I was able to resolve api.nuget.org in Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, enable TLS 1.2 to talk to the new NuGet server.
[Microsoft DevBlogs on NuGet TLS status](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org-stage-1/)

Comment: https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/10/how-to-activate-tls-1-2-on-windows-server-2008-r2-and-iis-7-5/