# Azure DevOps Server as NuGet "proxy" server

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-server, azure-devops-server-2019

I have Azure DevOps Server which will run build tasks on workstations without internet connection. The DevOps server itself can connect to internet.

I'm trying to configure Devops server in a way that when the build on one of the workstations needs a Nuget package, the server connects to the internet and downloads it, virtually serving as "proxy server" for build agents which are running on workstations without internet access.

I've configured Nuget feed and created service connection which points to that feed. However, whenever I try to use feed in build tasks, tasks fail either with "timed out" error

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to load
>   the service index for source
>   https://**************/_packaging/nuget_feed/nuget/v3/index.json. The
>   HTTP request to 'GET
>   https://**************/_packaging/nuget_feed/nuget/v3/index.json' has
>   timed out after 100000ms.)

or with:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server
>   Error - Failed to retrieve data from the upstream package source
>   'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': An error occurred while sending
>   the request

Can Azure DevOps Server function as "Nuget package proxy", and, if yes, how can it be configured to perform this task?

Comment: Yes, this should work. But is the server itself still behind a proxy server? That requires additional configuration which isn't well documented (and I don't know how well supported this is). You can configure the web proxy element in the web.config and the app.configs of Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: I suppose  you have proxy on your server, if yes, you could try to add add proxy settings into Nuget.Config file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me too,

I deleted upstream source and it worked out:

[image: delete upstream source]

Best regards