# NuGet feed in Azure DevOps is not accessible anymore (TF246017 / TF30040)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-devops-server-2019

I recently activated the new URL in Azure DevOps, moving from

```
https://xxx.visualstudio.com/
```

to

```
https://dev.azure.com/xxx
```

Consequently, the address to my NuGet feed also changed:

```
https://{xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/feed.xxx.ca/nuget/v3/index.json
```

to

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/feed.xxx.ca/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Everything works except for one thing. Now, I am unable to access my NuGet feed (using Visual Studio, Visual Studio for Mac & Rider). I end up with the following error:

> Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with
>   respect to project 'iOS', targeting 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0' Unable
>   to load the service index for source
>   https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/feed.xxx.ca/nuget/v3/index.json.

If I type the address in a browser, I get the following error:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF246017: Azure DevOps
>   Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the instance is
>   specified correctly, that the server that is hosting the database is
>   operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication
>   with the
>   server.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseConnectionException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"DatabaseConnectionException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3008}

**Question**

How do I fix it?

---

**Update #1**

There is a similar error described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086246/azure-devops-server-as-nuget-proxy-server). I am not using a proxy server.

---

**Update #2**

I am not seeing this error message when accessing the `index.json`:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF30040: The database is
>   not correctly configured. Contact your Azure DevOps Server
>   administrator.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.AzureClientIPRestrictedException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"AzureClientIPRestrictedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3007}

Comment: Could you still use https://{YourOrg}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{YourProject}/nuget/v3/index.json? I created a feed under pkgs.dev.azure.com, but i can also access via https://{YourOrg}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{YourProject}/nuget/v3/index.json

Comment: No, it does not work. I get the error shown in the **Update #2** section of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same [question developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/567616/nuget-feed-in-azure-devops-is-not-accessible-anymo.html) and got it fixed. It was due a problem on Microsoft's side as shown on the [dev.azure's status page](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history).