# Nuget Unable to load the service index for source (503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

The original requirement is to publish a nuget package (.nupkg) into an artifact feed (named Framework).

[image: nuhg]

Therefore we use a Azure DevOps Server (version 2019.0.1) behind a proxy. I try to add .nupkg files manually with the `nuget.exe` (Version: 5.0.2.5988)

```
nuget.exe push -Source "Framework" -ApiKey AzureDevOps FrameworkA.1.1.0.nupkg
```

**As result I get:**

```
NuGet Version: 5.0.2.5988
Unable to load the service index for source http://localserver:8070/Samples/_packaging/Framework/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Der Antwortstatuscode gibt keinen Erfolg an: 503 (Service Unavailable).
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source http://localserver:8070/Samples/_packaging/Framework/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Der Antwortstatuscode gibt keinen Erfolg an: 503 (Service Unavailable).
   bei System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   bei NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__8.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.PackageUpdateResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Commands.CommandRunnerUtility.<GetPackageUpdateResource>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.<Run>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
```

I read [Nuget connection attempt failed “Unable to load the service index for source”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source) and add proxy information `http_proxy`, `http_proxy.user` and `http_proxy.password` (also `https_proxy` version) but that do not solve my problem.

**In result my config looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
    <add key="Framework" value="http://localserver:8070/Samples/_packaging/Framework/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://www-proxy:8000" />
    <add key="http_proxy.user" value="domain\user" />
    <add key="http_proxy.password" value="encryped password" />
    <add key="https_proxy" value="http://www-proxy:8000" />
    <add key="https_proxy.user" value="domain\user" />
    <add key="https_proxy.password" value="non encryped password (nuget know's why)" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Is there any way to make a more diagnostics to that error?

Comment: HTTP 503 is a server side error, you're not going to be able to get more information on the client side (you can always try opening `http://localserver:8070/Samples/_packaging/Framework/nuget/v3/index.json` in your web browser, Fiddler or whatever other tools you use for generic HTTP debugging). Ultimately you need to get `localserver` working and only the server side logs might help.