# NuGet with Docket Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-for-windows

Running docker build command in PowerShell and getting:

> Unable to load the service index for source

I've litterly tried all the solutions provided here:
[Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source) and here:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5358. I don't have any problems with visual studio 2017 on nuget restore packages.

I'm not behind a proxy or anything. I'm able to see json output if I browse to: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

[image: c#]

my NuGet.Config in (AppData):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Why does docker fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After counless hours trying to figure this out this fix worked for me:

Open: c:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json and add the following line:

```
"dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
```

My daemon file now looks like this:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true,
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8"],
}
```