# VS2019 - Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a brand new profile on an existing Windows 10 PC.  The PC does not use a proxy, and proxy settings are turned off.  I also have no proxy environment variables, and am able to access the json via a web browser.

I have tried following all the advice from other posts on here, such as deleting the nuget.config file, and editing the devenv.exe.config file to add proxy settings but nothing works.

I even tried turning off my firewall, but still no luck.  What else can I do here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much digging, I finally found the solution in this post:

[Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)

[Razi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58851687/11089361) regarding TLS 1.3 protocols in the registry.

Comment: Hi devonuto, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it just a reminder :)