# Proxy interfering with Azure Server/ NuGet Push Error404

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I tried to Push a nupkg to Artifacts in Azure DevOps Server, but it fails with the following error:

```
---> (Inner Exception #0) NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source http://<DomainName>/nuget/v3/index.json ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

I suspect that the problem might be the corporate's proxy that interferes with Azure DevOps Server.

Proxy's configuration looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://ep.threatpulse.net:80" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Also, I tried to configure the proxy settings and it still didn't work.

Does anybody have any idea about what could be wrong or how can I fix this?

*Version Dev17.M153.5*

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I tried the solution you gave me but it didn't work. I'm waiting to see if the IT office can solve it. Meanwhile I'm checking the thread you gave me.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Proxy interfering with Azure Server/ NuGet Push Error404

Yes, that error is indeed caused by proxy and what you did is also correct.

Just make sure you have add proxy settings into `Nuget.Config` file, which located in following path:

```
%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.config
```

NuGet.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://ep.threatpulse.net:80" />
        <add key="https_proxy" value="http://ep.threatpulse.net:80" />
    </config>

  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>

</configuration>
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source) for some more details.

If it still not work for you, I suggest you contact your office IT to confirm proxy setting.

Hope this helps.