# `nuget restore`: NuGet resolves the wrong version of package dependency

Tags: windows, nuget

I have two machines, my dev machine and the build server. For the latter `nuget restore` does try to pull a wrong version for a particular package

```
16:15:48 Failed to retrieve information about 'Autofac' from remote source 'https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Autofac'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
```

I've checked the complete solution and there is no rederence to version `2.0.0` but only `4.x.x`. More strangely the `nuget restore` works fine on my dev machien

```
D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT
λ nuget restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'.
Restoring NuGet package Autofac.4.9.4.
...
  GET https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Packages(Id='Autofac',Version='4.9.4')
...
  OK https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Packages(Id='Autofac',Version='4.9.4') 31ms
...
  GET https://artifactory.intra/artifactory/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Download/Autofac/4.9.4
...
  OK https://artifactory.intra/artifactory/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Download/Autofac/4.9.4 95ms
...
Installing Autofac 4.9.4.
...
Adding package 'Autofac.4.9.4' to folder 'D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT\packages'
...
Added package 'Autofac.4.9.4' to folder 'D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT\packages'
....
Restoring NuGet package Autofac.4.9.0.
  GET https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Packages(Id='Autofac',Version='4.9.0')
Adding package 'MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2' to folder 'D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT\packages'
  OK https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Packages(Id='Autofac',Version='4.9.0') 37ms
  GET https://artifactory.intra/artifactory/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Download/Autofac/4.9.0
  OK https://artifactory.intra/artifactory/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Download/Autofac/4.9.0 10ms
Installing Autofac 4.9.0.
...
Adding package 'Autofac.4.9.0' to folder 'D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT\packages'
  GET https://artifactory.intra/artifactory/api/nuget/virtual-nuget/Download/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/4.3.0
...
Added package 'Autofac.4.9.0' to folder 'D:\development\data\svn\MYPROJECT\packages'
...
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\papanito\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
Feeds used:
    https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
Installed:
    18 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

Both have the same `nuget` version installed with `choco install nuget.commandline`. I also distribute the same `Nuget.Config` to both machines.

**Update**

Further up in the log I can see the following

```
 Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.intra/api/nuget/virtual-nuget.
07:43:45   Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
```

Maybe due to the fact that the index cannot be read the wrong version is downloaded? However, still doesn't explain why on my dev machine all works fine.

**Update 2**

So there is a Visual Studio 2017 installed on the build server. I've checked various other sources and tried some things, without success.

- [Nuget connection attempt failed “Unable to load the service index for source”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source/58851687#58851687)
- [Package Manager Error: Unable to load the service index for source (bad proxy settings)#](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2880#issuecomment-601314208)

Checked various files for proxy settings but none of them has one, which is good

- `C:\Windows\syste - m32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

Answer (score 0):

By the error code, it looks to be an issue getting to that NuGet package from your build server.

If you run Fiddler (and configure it to [decrypt HTTPS](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS)), what's the status code you get when the index file is retrieved from your private NuGet server ?

Below a 200 OK while retrieving the Autofac NuGet package from nuget.org:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I appears the issue is related to a wrong `NuGetDefaults.config`: As soon as there are `username` and `password` defined for a source in that file, nuget fails.