# encrypt password for http_proxy, access nuget source

Tags: c#, .net, macos, nuget, dotnet-cli

Over here [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41185443/3310334)  I saw many solutions proposed for the

> ```
> Unable to load the service index for source ...
> ```

Error that I find myself getting on an attempted `dotnet build` right now.

I see suggestions to put XML like either of these

```xml
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <vstsfeed>
        <add key="Username" value="yourname@company.com" />
        <add key="Password" value="this is an encrypted password" >
        <!-- add key="ClearTextPassword" value="not recommended password" -->
    </vstsfeed>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

```xml
<config>
     <!-- Proxy settings -->
     <add key="http_proxy" value="host" />
     <add key="http_proxy.user" value="username" />
     <add key="http_proxy.password" value="encrypted_password" />
</config>
```

Into `Nuget.Config`.

How are the passwords encrypted? What should go into the encrypted_password placeholder spaces?