# use ssh key for accessing nuget source

Tags: c#, macos, nuget, dotnet-cli

Over here  I saw many solutions proposed for the

I am getting an error on `dotnet build`:

> ```
> Unable to load the service index for source ...
> ```

I saw solutions here: [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41185443/3310334) but none work for me yet (I don't know how to "encrypt a password")

I wonder if I can authenticate using my ssh key? How could I set that up?

Comment: If you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315140/43846) - _If you are getting this error, but you don't have a proxy server_ - I think it's telling you to comment out or remove those lines if they are in the config file.

Comment: @stuartd my config was completely empty except for a default api.nuget.org package source

Comment: If you don't have a proxy server, you don't need to add those lines. If you do, you might just need `http_proxy` unless your proxy uses credentials.