# i want to install Some nuget packages like "microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors" but there are erros like below

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)

Comment: Duplicate Question: [Nuget connection attempt failed “Unable to load the service index for source”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)