# nuget packages fails to load

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

my NuGet packages are not loading, therefor I'm facing errors right from the beginning.
it was fine the other day but now it's not loading and I can't find a solution.
it happens with every MAUI project, even with a new MAUI project[image]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source ?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I tried using Tls 1.2 but that didn't work for me
after some time I went back to the registry editor to

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> 1.2\Client

and changed the value of DisabledByDefault from 1 to 0 and restarted visual studio, and it worked. I built my app and all the dependencies load up.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting %AppData%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config as mentioned here: [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)