# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in vs2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 after reinstalling Windows, and when I reopen my project written with .NET Core 6, I get this error when building the project.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYrHb.png)

Comment: Try rebooting the machine. Also have you checked it the url is accessible via browser?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I checked and it is correct