# Unable to install any NuGet packages to my .NET application

Tags: nuget, .net-framework-version, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server, nuget-spec

Unable to install any NuGet packages to my .NET application and getting below error.

NuGet\Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)