# Error with Skaffold and NuGet during .NET Core Docker build

Tags: .net, docker, nuget, skaffold

I'm encountering an issue while using Skaffold to build a .NET Core Docker image for my project. I've configured my skaffold.yaml file to build and deploy my application, but during the build phase, I'm encountering the following NuGet error:

```
[build 5/8] RUN dotnet restore "XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj":
0.978 Determining projects to restore...
14.80 /src/XXXX.Students.Domain/XXXX.Students.Domain.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/
src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj]
14.80 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
14.85 Failed to restore /src/XXXX.Students.Domain/XXXX.Students.Domain.csproj (in 13.6 sec).
27.63 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
40.43 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
53.17 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
65.90 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
78.92 /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
78.93 Failed to restore /src/XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj (in 1.29 min).
```

````
Here is my skaffold.yaml file configuration for reference:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta25
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: students-api
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: students-api
      custom:
        buildCommand: bash ../../../Scripts/skaffold-build.sh ./XXXX.Students.API/Dockerfile
        dependencies:
          paths:
            - XXXX.Students.API/**
            - XXXX.Students.Domain/**
deploy:
    kustomize:
      paths:
      - ../../../k8s/students-api/overlays/local
````

And here is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj", "XXXX.Students.API/"]
COPY ["XXXX.Students.Domain/XXXX.Students.Domain.csproj", "XXXX.Students.Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "XXXX.Students.API/XXXX.Students.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/XXXX.Students.API"
RUN dotnet build "XXXX.Students.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "XXXX.Students.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXXX.Students.API.dll"]
```

I run this service by command:

```
skaffold dev --default-repo=localhost:5000 -f skaffold.yaml --cache-artifacts=false
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to NuGet configuration or network settings. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully build my Docker image with Skaffold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)

Comment: @Max I've tried, no one works for me .

Comment: try this: `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 sh`, once started on prompt digit: `apt update`, `apt install curl` and then `curl -X GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` and post the output

Comment: @Max thanks for instruction, I displayed this information after performing your operation
`# curl -X GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.`

Comment: @Max I've tried adding commands like this:
`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates

RUN dotnet restore "XXXX.Accounts.API/XXXX.Accounts.API.csproj"`but  same errors come out, I don't know how to try next.

Comment: Try to update the image `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0` otherwise, I think is a network issue [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1100480/wsl-docker-curl-60-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: Was there any luck with this issue? Facing the same with aspnet:8.0 image