# Certificate validation on private nuget feed fails in MAUI solutions

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, nuget, maui

After updating Visual Studio to 17.8.0 and further we have the problem to consume a private NuGet feed.

The private NuGet feed is a [NuGet.Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server) instance and is reachable from the local network. The instance has a valid server certificate and the server certificate has a valid cert chain, which can be validated by all clients in the network.

Everything is going well, for non MAUI solutions. By that I mean every solution, which does not include a MAUI-Application.

If we try to get NuGet-Packages from the server inside of a MAUI solution, we get the following error:

> [LocalServer] Unable to load the service index for source https://`<SERVER>`/nuget.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Did something drastically changed for MAUI or VisualStudio22 to consume a private NuGet-Feed?

Comment: You can check this article about how to set the [Nuget Feeds](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=c2fa0c12fc5e6a9fJmltdHM9MTcwMjI1MjgwMCZpZ3VpZD0zYzFmMjQ0Ny1mMmNhLTYwYTItMmFlNi0zN2Q0ZjNjYjYxOWUmaW5zaWQ9NTIyNA&ptn=3&ver=2&hsh=3&fclid=3c1f2447-f2ca-60a2-2ae6-37d4f3cb619e&psq=Certificate+validation+on+private+nuget+feed+fails+in+MAUI+solutions&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly90cmFpbGhlYWR0ZWNobm9sb2d5LmNvbS91c2luZy1wcml2YXRlLW51Z2V0LWZlZWRzLXdpdGgtbmV0LW1hdWktYW5kLWF6dXJlLXBpcGVsaW5lcy8&ntb=1).

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Sry, but this doesnt cover the question at all. We don't use Azure Pipelines, instead we use the NuGet.Server and host it ourself on a server inside our network, without any authentication, because it's not reachable outside our network.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions on this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source

Comment: And try using the command line - still the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly yes. The same issue. I already cleared the cache, reinstalled VS22 used another PC and so on. Same problem

Comment: We have a similar setup to your and I recall running into something similar. In that particular case I discovered that while the cert chain told me it was valid it turned out the cert was actually expired. I would go and take a close look at your cert chain and verify it.

Comment: The cert chain is valid. I tried to made a second server with a new chain and have the same described problem.

Comment: It works on my side, if you start nuget server on the PC, will the issue still exists?

Comment: Yes it still exists, when I have a MauiApplication (and only if there is one) in my solution. At least when I configure it with my domain name instead of localhost. But localhost is not a valid approach, when distributing packages inside of the network