# Dotnet restore fails when build docker

Tags: docker, nuget, dotnet-restore

I have a problem with dotnet restore command used in docker container.

I am using standard Dockerfile generated by VS2022 for simple console project in .net 7.
DockerFile is generated by Visual Studio.

Docker Engine v24.0.7
Docker Desktop v4.26.1

DockerFile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1.csproj", "."]
#RUN curl -i -k -X GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 
RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Output :

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --force-rm -t consoleapp1:dev --target build .
[+] Building 7.4s (8/11)                                                                                                                                                                               docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 898B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 464B                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0@sha256:4be8ff7cb847f9e7ea1ac194920b0a6d41956af89f934b61a2ce64dc8563471c                                                                                    0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0@sha256:4be8ff7cb847f9e7ea1ac194920b0a6d41956af89f934b61a2ce64dc8563471c                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 184B                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [ConsoleApp1.csproj, .]                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp1.csproj"                                                                                                                                              7.3s
------
 > [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp1.csproj":
0.913   Determining projects to restore...
7.194 /src/ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
7.242   Failed to restore /src/ConsoleApp1.csproj (in 6.13 sec).
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |     COPY ["ConsoleApp1.csproj", "."]
  10 |     #RUN curl -i -k -X GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  11 | >>> RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp1.csproj"
  12 |     COPY . .
  13 |     WORKDIR "/src/."
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore \"./././ConsoleApp1.csproj\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I try this request from container and I could hit nuget :

```
curl -v -k https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

I try severals solutions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source)) posted in stackoverflow and the web but I have same issue...

**UPDATE 1 :**

I fixed the problem, my company use a proxy. We have disabled the proxy for tests and `dotnet restore` command not failed.
All I have to do is import my company certificate in the container.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Import certificates and update :

```
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1.csproj", "."]
COPY ["./Certificate/myCertificate.crt", "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCertificate.crt"]
COPY  ["./Certificate/myCertificate.crt", "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCertificate.crt"]
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN dotnet restore "./././ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
```